# PostgreSQL: Make data appear in different rows instead of same row

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, sum

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Blue",
    SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'purple' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Purple",
    SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'yellow' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Yellow",
    SUM(CASE WHEN color= 'blue' THEN 1 WHEN color= 'yellow' THEN -1 END) AS "Mixed"
FROM table;
```

And  the result gives me a table with 4 columns and 1 row:

e.g.
Blue | Purple | Yellow | Mixed

But I want the results to appear in 4 rows and 1 column like this:

Blue

- Blue
- Purple
- Yellow
- Mixed

Does anyone have any idea what I could do in this case? I've been working on this forever.

Comment: Presumably, you want two columns in the result set, not one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a pain, because of the mixed value -- a simple aggregation is not sufficient.  So, use a lateral join to unpivot:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Blue,
             SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'purple' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Purple,
             SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'yellow' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yellow,
             SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'blue' THEN 1 WHEN color = 'yellow' THEN -1 END) AS Mixed
      FROM t
     ) t CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES ('Blue', blue), ('Purple', purple), ('Yellow', yellow), ('Mixed', mixed)
     ) v(which, val);
```

Actually, in Postgres, you could also write this as:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE color = 'blue') AS Blue,
             COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE color = 'purple') AS Purple,
             COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE color = 'yellow') AS Yellow
      FROM t
     ) t CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES ('Blue', blue), ('Purple', purple), ('Yellow', yellow), ('Mixed', blue - yellow)
     ) v(which, val)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! (the second option)

Answer (score 0):

For the first 3 counters you can `group by color` and aggregate and use `UNION ALL` for `Mixed`:

```
SELECT color, COUNT(*) counter
WHERE color IN ('blue', 'purple', 'yellow') -- remove this line if these are all the possible colors
FROM table
GROUP BY color
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mixed', SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'blue' THEN 1 WHEN color = 'yellow' THEN -1 END)
WHERE color IN ('blue', 'yellow')
FROM table
```

This query will return 2 columns.
If you don't want the 1st column then:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) counter
WHERE color IN ('blue', 'purple', 'yellow') -- remove this line if these are all the possible colors
FROM table
GROUP BY color
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'blue' THEN 1 WHEN color = 'yellow' THEN -1 END)
FROM table
WHERE color IN ('blue', 'yellow')
```